# Material UI icon for Link Button not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Material UI icon does not appear on the button with `variant=link` which acts like a hyperlink.

```
import MailOutlineIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MailOutline';

signInButton: {
    textTransform: "none",
    width: "80%",
    backgroundColor: "#e8e8e8"
  },

<Button 
   variant="link"
   color="default"
   className={classes.signInButton}
   startIcon={<MailOutlineIcon />}
   href="/signin"
>
   Sign in with Email
</Button>
```

Comment: I tried both methods. It's not working. The button is present inside parent elements like this- <Card><Grid container><Grid item><Button>

Comment: when I inspect the button it shows - start icon="[object Object]

Answer (score 6):

```
import GitHubIcon from '@material-ui/icons/GitHub';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
<Link href="http://www.google.com" className={classes.link} target="_blank" >
    <GitHubIcon/>
</Link>
```

on clicking to the GitHubIcon you will redirect to the new tab because of target="_blank" this.. and target="_blank" is optional

Answer (score 0):

change

```
import MailOutlineIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MailOutline';
```

to

```
import MailOutlineIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MailOutlined';
```

demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-zj2jx